# Why isn't having a masechet with the name as the seder a concern in Taharot?

Tags: names, mishna, masechet-moed-katan, maseches-taharos

Kehati's introduction to Moed Katan says that it is not called Moed so as not to cause confusion, as the seder has the same name. However, this doesn't seem to be a concern for masechet Taharot in seder Taharot.

Why not?

Comment: Does R Kehati cite an earlier source?

Comment: @DoubleAA Not that I can see.

Comment: I have a nagging feeling that טהרות has different Nikkud in the two cases.

Comment: possibly helpful http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28490/zeraim-moed-nashim-nezikim-kodshim-taharos-why-not-moadim?rq=1#comment68986_28490

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that Kehati cites that as the only reason it is called *Moed Kattan*. The tractate focuses mainly on Hol Hamo'ed, which is a "small" holiday.

Comment: @DoubleAA The feeling that nags you rings a bell for me and I think it has come up in comments here. Are those interrogable?

Comment: @WAF shoulda tried searching the main content too http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30106/759

Comment: Also Meseches Taharos is really a Lashon Naki for less Chamor Tumaos which the Mesechta. Like Rishon, Sheini, Shlishi. Not Avos HaTumah. See Kehati's introduction for Meseches Taharos. (I'm pretty sure its he cites the Rambam Perush HaMishnayos, If I remember correctly)

Comment: Please note that _Tif'eres Yisra'el_, in his introduction to _N'zikin_, says that the first 3 _masechtos_ comprise a _maschta_ called "N'zikin" and that each _bava_ is a piece of that _masechta_, divided by content. At least some of this is based on Ramba"m's commentary.